# Polish fonts aren't working in console Fedora 20

Tags: linux, fedora, language

I've got a problem with polish characters like źżćó in console on my Fedora 20 (kernel 3.13.3-201). Using LXTerminal or putty (via SSH) is everything ok.
When I set: 
`setfont latarcyrheb-sun16`
, it's back to normal, but I wanna do that automaticaly.

I was trying change grub configuration (in `/etc/default/grub add vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 vconsole.lang=pl_PL.UTF-8` then --> `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`) but after restart nothing happend. Still the same problem? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add those commands to your shell's login files. Just open `~/.profile` (create it if it doesn't exist) and add this line to it:

```
setfont latarcyrheb-sun16
```

Now every time you log in, that command will be run and your fonts should work. Note that if you already ahve a file called `~/.bash_profile`, you should add the line to it instead since bash will read that instead of `~/.profile` if present.